# Running parallel flows in power automate desktop

Tags: power-platform, power-automate-desktop

I have multiple flows that i need to execute parallely as these are independent of each other

I have scenario where i have to execute 2000+ flows on a single day.Each flow is different and independent of each other(What it does is that it checks for files in 2000+ locations each day and fetches them).Is there a way that i can execute these flows parallely since they are independent.?

Comment: I don't think they can execute on the same machine. if you have a pool of machines they should be able to execute simultaneously, one on each machine. PAD is possibly not the correct tool for the job. Does your process do any UI interaction? if not it's worth going down the powershell and/or C# and/or python path.